# How can I flush cache in the Firefox?

Tags: silverlight, caching

Here is my code line in the default.aspx

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

But Firefox does not work. How can I flush cache in the Firefox? BTW, I am using Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

FireFox is a thought one with cache. Witch version are you dealing with?

You could try this.

```
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        Response.Expires = -1441;
```